# Why @Transactional ignores Lazy fetch in some cases

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, lazy-loading

(I checked questions for this area - they do not ask the same).

I have a standard class *Person* with *FetchType.LAZY* on 'addresses' field.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    //...constructors, getters and setters

}
```

The following method generates **two** SQL queries, to both Address and Person tables **BEFORE** initializing Addresses by getAddresses() method. I do not understand why because use *FetchType.LAZY*.

```
@Transactional
public void testLazyLoadingTransactional() throws Exception {

    Optional<Person> person = personRepository.findById(1); 

    System.out.println(""); //here I set a breakpoint 

    // here I see two SQL queries in a console
    // "select person ..." and "select address ..."

    if (person.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(person.get().getAddresses());
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundException("Person not found");
    }
}
```

---

Also I figured out that if in the body of the method I **do not** use getAddresses() then I got only one SQL query to Person table.

If so

```
@Transactional
public void testLazyLoadingTransactional() throws Exception {
    Optional<Person> person = personRepository.findById(1);  
}
```

then I see ONE SQL queries in a console "select person ...".

Why in the first case Lazy fetch is ignored?

Comment: How do you know that the query is executed before calling getAddresses() (which, BTW, is not what initializes the collection and generates the query)? Post code and output illustrating what you actually get, and post what you expect instead.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see generated Hibernate queries in a console with such properties in application.properties: 
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

Comment: Your method prints the addresses. To print the addresses, they need to be loaded. What's surprising about seeing the query loading the addresses in the logs?

Comment: Surprizing is that SQL query to Address table done BEFORE calling addresses for printing.

Comment: Again, how do you know that the queriy is executed before you call getAddresses()? Post code producing output, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: I set a breakpoint on System.out.println() before - see edited question - and trace SQL queries in debug mode.

Comment: Don't use breakpoints to make such diagnosis. The debugger shows values of variables, and to show them, it iterates over them, and that initializes them.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!